# Behavior of 32 bit applications in 64 bit Windows (memory)

Tags: windows, memory, memory-management, shared-memory

I am developing a 32 bit application in .NET that for various reasons cannot be compiled as a 64 bit application.

I need to run many of these concurrently and they use a lot of memory. I want to load up a Windows 7 box with tonnes of memory and consequently would like to use the 64 bit version of Windows 7 so that we can put many gigabytes of RAM on those boxes.

My question is this: The maximum memory used by each instance of my app is ~500mb. In Windows 7 64bit, these 32-bit applications will run (I assume) using the WOW64 emulation layer in Windows. As I begin to run more and more of these instances concurrently, will they all be stuck running in the bottom 2gb of ram, or will Windows allocate memory for them using all of the higher-address range of memory possible within 64-bit Windows? Is the addressable-memory limitation of 32 bit software only a per-instance limitation in this case, or will all the instances be limited to the bottom 2gb of ram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing memory (physical address space) with virtual address space. You can put more than 4GB of memory into a 32-bit system; you don't need to move to 64-bit to gain physical address space. Each process gets its own virtual address space, so each one will get its own 2GB of user-mode address space to play with. (Or 3GB if /3GB or 4GB if running on WOW64 with /LARGEADDRESSAWARE.)

Comment: You do need to move to 64 bit to gain physical address space if you are using client edition of the OS as opposed to server editions